# How to Share Admin$ using RDP activex control?

Tags: c#-4.0, activex, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-connection

I 'm trying to share admin$ or c$ with my remote desktop, and need to apply some settings after or before start connecting.
It could be done simply with mstsc setting tab. But it is completely unknown to me while going to deploy it's c# code. There is administrator permission on both devices and "net use" command does not work.

I use rdp activex control in Windows form application. Like below

```
AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting rdp;

     .....
 rdp.AdvancedSettings8.RedirectDrives=true;
```

It get connected after loading but no share drive will be stablished with my local computer.
How to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Did you check if you can see the drive that you are trying to map in MSTSC: start MSTSC -> Show Options -> Local Resources -> More -> Drives ?

Comment: Alternatively, you can look at the other APIs that RedirectDrives uses underneath:
• IMsRdpDriveCollection (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381374(v=vs.85).aspx)
• IMsRdpDrive (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381371(v=vs.85).aspx)
• IMsRdpClientNonScriptable3::DriveCollection (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381270(v=vs.85).aspx) 
• IMsRdpDriveCollection::DriveCount  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381377(v=vs.85).aspx) 
• IMsRdpDriveCollection::DriveByIndex (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381376(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: And • IMsRdpDrive::RedirectionState (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381791(v=vs.85).aspx)